# Given composition rules, determining whether a continuous map between smooth functions is a pseudodifferential operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $M$ be a closed manifold, and let $P:C^{\infty}(M)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(M)$ be a continuous linear map in the smooth Fréchet topologies. In what is to come, if it helps, one can assume further that $P:H^{s}(M)\rightarrow H^{s+m}(M)$ continously for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$ for some $m>0$.

Suppose that there are pseudodifferential operators $E,A:  C^{\infty}(M)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(M)$, with $E$ elliptic, such that,
$$
EP=A.
$$
Can one determine that $P$ must also be a pseudodifferential operator? It seems that this cannot be observed directly, because if one composes both sides by a parametrix $E^{-1}$ for $E$, it holds that
$$
P+KP=E^{-1}A
$$
where $E^{-1}E=I+K$, $K$ being a smoothing integral operator. $KP$ seems to be smoothing but I find myself unable to explain why it is within the calculus.

Another approach I was thinking about is to use the Schwartz kernel theorem to apriori construct the symbol of $P$, and show by the composition above that it must be in the right class, but I got a bit lost in the details.

Any help or reference on this will be most appreciated.

Comment: Isn’t the composition of a smoothing operator with any operator of finite order smoothing because the output is always smooth?

Comment: By finite order you mean its range is finite dimensional? But $P$ has no finite dimensional range

Comment: No. Order of differentiation. The $m$ in your question.

Comment: I don't know that $P:\mathcal{D}'(M)\rightarrow \mathcal{D}'(M)$. Even if I did, does the fact that $KP:\mathcal{D}'(M)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(M)$ alone would imply that $KP$ is in the calculus?

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked with pseudodifferential operators, but I am under the impression that any smoothing operator is a pseudodifferential operator. Then since $P$ is the composition of two pseudodifferential operators modulo a smoothing operator, it is a pseudodifferential operator.

Comment: I couldn't find any reference of this or prove it myself. Can you please help with that? :)

Comment: I believe that the Schwartz kernel theorem tells you the operator can be written as an integral operator where the kernel is a distribution. If the operator is smoothing the kernel is smooth. Such an operator fits the definition of a pseudodifferential operator. But you shouldn’t take my word for it. You should work out the details yourself.